# remove the duplicate key and values in list of dictionaries and append unique list of values to a key

Tags: python, dictionary

```
list_of_dict=[{'f_text':'sample', 'symbol':'*', 'f_id':246, 'record_id':'4679', 'flag': 'N'},
{'f_text':'sample', 'symbol':'*', 'f_id':246, 'record_id':'4680', 'flag': 'N'},
{'f_text':'other text', 'symbol':'!#', 'f_id':247, 'record_id':'4678', 'flag': 'N'}]
```

in the above list of dictionaries the first and second lines has same 'f_id':'246'. so I'm trying to remove duplicate key and values in the dictionary and make 'record_id':['4679','4680'].

I'm expecting the below output

```
[{'f_text':'sample', 'symbol':'*', 'f_id':246, 'record_id':['4679',4680], 'flag': 'N'},
{'f_text':'other text', 'symbol':'!#', 'f_id':247, 'record_id':'4678', 'flag': 'N'}]
```

i've tried below code:

```
for dictionary in list_of_dict:
    if dictionary['record_id'] == int(record_id):
        dictionary['flag'] = 'CHECKED'
    sort_footnote = sorted(get_footnote, key=lmabda k:k['flag'])
```

please suggest the better solution for my problem

with the below code i'm trying to remove the duplicate records using set

```
lst = [{*l[0], 'record_id': set([x['record_id'] for x in l])} if len(l:=list(v)) > 1 else l[0] for _, v in groupby(sorted(list_of_dict, key=lambda x: x['f_id']), key=lambda x: x['f_id'])] 

output: res = [{'f_text': 'sample', 'symbol': '', 'f_id': 246, 'record_id': {'4679', '4680'}, 'flag': 'N'},
```

when i'm doing: return jsonify(res)

i'm getting error: object of type set is not JSON serializable

Comment: so duplicate keys can be any key and follow the procedure to keep value in list, or it is just for `f_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@U12-Forward's answer works only if the input is pre-sorted, with records of the same `f_id`s already grouped together.

A better-rounded approach that works regardless of the order of the input would be to build a dict that maps `f_id`s to respective dicts, but convert the `record_id` value to a list when there are multiple records with the same `f_id`s:

```
mapping = {}
for d in list_of_dict:
    try:
        entry = mapping[d['f_id']] # raises KeyError
        entry['record_id'].append(d['record_id']) # raises AttributeError
    except KeyError:
        mapping[d['f_id']] = d
    except AttributeError:
        entry['record_id'] = [entry['record_id'], d['record_id']]
print(list(mapping.values()))
```

This outputs:

```
[{'f_text': 'sample', 'symbol': '*', 'f_id': 246, 'record_id': ['4679', '4680'], 'flag': 'N'}, {'f_text': 'other text', 'symbol': '!#', 'f_id': 247, 'record_id': '4678', 'flag': 'N'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `itertools.groupby` and group the groups and merge the `record_id` values:

```
from itertools import groupby
[{**l[0], 'record_id': [x['record_id'] for x in l]} if len(l:=list(v)) > 1 else l[0] for _, v in groupby(sorted(list_of_dict, key=lambda x: x['f_id']), key=lambda x: x['f_id'])]
```

Output:

```
[{'f_text': 'sample', 'symbol': '*', 'f_id': 246, 'record_id': ['4679', '4680'], 'flag': 'N'}, {'f_text': 'other text', 'symbol': '!#', 'f_id': 247, 'record_id': '4678', 'flag': 'N'}]
```

Or define the lambda once:

```
from itertools import groupby
func = lambda x: x['f_id']
[{**l[0], 'record_id': [x['record_id'] for x in l]} if len(l:=list(v)) > 1 else l[0] for _, v in groupby(sorted(list_of_dict, key=func), key=func)]
```

Comment: This works only if the input is pre-sorted, which is not necessarily the case for the question.

Comment: @blhsing Well, who knows, in the OP's actual data it might not be sorted

Comment: That's the point. Since there is no guarantee that the OP's data is pre-sorted, your answer would fail when the input isn't in a perfect order.

Comment: @blhsing Idid sort...

Comment: Ah, I missed the part where `sorted` is called. In that case the answer would indeed work but is simply not as efficient as it could be, requiring *O(n log n)* in time complexity with the sorting involved.

Comment: @blhsing Ah. Yeah I will add something else, a bit more efficient possibly

Comment: @blhsing Edited mine

Comment: @U12-Forward thanks your help. i'm getting duplicate record_id. so i've used set to remove them.
[{**l[0], 'record_id': set([x['record_id'] for x in l])} if len(l:=list(v)) > 1 else l[0] for _, v in groupby(sorted(list_of_dict, key=lambda x: x['f_id']), key=lambda x: x['f_id'])]

output:

res = [{'f_text': 'sample', 'symbol': '*', 'f_id': 246, 'record_id': {'4679', '4680'}, 'flag': 'N'},

when i'm doing: return jsonify(res)
i'm getting error: object of type set is not JSON serializable